Why was `fftshift` invented for? Why not `fftshift` by default the output of the current `fft` implementations?
So today I finally understood what is the purpose of the fftshift function found in both Matlab and Numpy & Scipy implementations. Summary of my understanding:

The natural order of fft's return values, does not match a linear space of frequencies from -dt to dt.
Hence, to get a frequency array that matches an array of frequency terms (from the output of fft), you either need to fftshift a linspace from -1/dt to +1/dt, or you'd need to fftshift the output of fft.

I am wondering though: Why isn't the fft function implemented in Matlab, Numpy and Scipy don't simply shift the output of it such that we'd get values that match linearly spaced frequencies from -1/dt to +1/dt? I'm sure there is a CPU/memory performance consideration here, but it'd be nice to get a thorough explanation for that.
Even if the CPU/memory performance consideration will be justified, it'd be nice to hear about examples of calculations that won't require you to fftshift a linearly spaced frequencies from -1/dt to +1/dt (or use Numpy's fftfreq), and therefor that would be more performant thanks to the fft returning an array in it's current, natural order.
One example I could think about for the above performance gain is convolution, which can be implemented as element-wise multiplication of fft outputs, (which therefor don't care about the order of the values, as long as it is consistent of course).
Perhaps there are other reasons not to fftshift by default the output of fft, which are worth mentioning.

The DFT is defined mathematically that way. So the question is why it is defined that way in maths. To me, it does feel more natural that the exponents in the imaginary exponentials increase from 0 to N − 1 (see here). Also, with your proposal the cases for N odd or even need to be treated differently, as in the latter case there is no center frequency. The expressions for the start and end indices in the sum that defines the DFT would be more cumbersome

Also, I'm not sure whether the beautiful symmetry between direct and inverse DFT (just a change of sign in the exponent and a multiplying constant) would be maintained with your suggested definition

The only time you need to apply fftshift is for visualization. Somehow people prefer to look at the frequency range -N/2 to N/2 rather than 0 to N-1. But this is just our preference, any computations you do are not concerned with this. Don’t think of fftshift as rearranging the FFT output, but rather as shifting the window over which we look at the periodic frequency domain.

@CrisLuengo a good example where I'm sure you'd agree with me it is natural to view the frequency range from -N/2 to N/2 is the classical Gaussian Fourier transform that should produce a Gaussian as well - take a Gaussian with mean at 0, corresponding to values from -x0 to x0; Run fft on it; Isn't it natural to expect a shifted sample of a Gaussian from -1/dx to 1/dx?

That is exactly what I mean with "for visualization". If you're not looking at it, it doesn't matter whether it looks pretty or not.

Calling this merely visualization is an understatement IMO. In general, usually what you are interested when inspecting a signal's Fourier transform, is interesting peaks in it's spectrum, and there it would also be natural if it would have been ordered from -1/dx to 1/dx.. The purpose of my question is to get examples of cases where it is natural to view or perform calculations upon the output of fft when it is ordered in it's current, natural order.
